# Can I install SRAM red force 22 on my Triban RC 120 (rim brakes)

Tags: replacement, groupsets

Bought my bike (Tribal RC120) last year and recently felt the need for a better groupset. Would SRAM red force 22 fit my frame?

[Bike](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/road-bikes/triban-rc120-review/)

[Group Set](https://www.bike24.com/p257505.html)

Comment: Aside - you don't need to change the brake calipers to change the transmission parts of the groupset.  Might be cheaper for you that way.

Answer (score 1):

The four most important standards that differ from bike to bike are:

- Front derailleur attachment (clamp vs braze on) -- the rear derailleur mounting is always the same
- Front derailleur cable pull details -- the rear derailleur always has a stop on the derailleur itself
- Rear cassette attachment
- Brake attachment

In this case, the groupset seems to support both clamp and braze on front derailleur attachments. They only list 31.8mm and 34.9mm but it shouldn't be too hard to find an adapter for 28.6mm frame tube diameter. So the front derailleur should work.

The front derailleur cable pull details can be observed by seeing whether the cable is directed under or over the front derailleur, and whether the housing goes all the way to the front derailleur (cable stop on the derailleur), or whether you have a cable stop on the frame. The pull details must be compatible with your existing setup. Also do note that it has become trendy to run full length housing to the derailleur with internal cable routing. In this case, you really do need a cable adjuster on the derailleur. Otherwise if your old setup has an adjuster on the derailleur but the new setup doesn't, you can use an inline adjuster.

What will not work with your existing wheels is the cassette. It requires Shimano compatible freehub body, for 11 speed road. Most likely your freehub body is 8-10 speed road (and does support 11 speed MTB but not 11 speed road).

I'm not a fan of dual pivot sidepull caliper brakes, so I can't comment on that extensively enough. What does vary is the brake reach. If your bike requires different reach than this particular groupset, it won't fit. For example, a reasonable bike would have room for at least 35mm tires with fenders (or even 40mm if ridden in areas where studded winter tires are required), but it unfortunately has become fashionable to offer brakes that support no more than 23mm tires with no fenders. I suspect this groupset will be supplied with the "fashionable" brakes, so if your frame allows decent tire size with fenders, the brakes won't fit.

Also there are different styles of mounting bolt for caliper brakes. If the mounting type differs, you might have difficulties installing the brakes.

Do also note that you probably don't have a compatible bottom bracket but buying one compatible with the new cranks is cheap and you most likely can find one compatible with your bike. After all, there are only few frame bottom bracket attachment standards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sounds like a lot of adjustments need to be made. In your opinion is it worth the effort?

Comment: "has become fashionable to offer brakes that support no more than 23mm tires" When? In 2000? Now even pros use 25 mils on normal tarmac and 28 in Paris-Roubaix or Strade Bianche so the frames must allow it. Hence also the popularity of disc brakes because the most severe limit on tyre width is often the rim brake. The fashion usually follows what the pros do and it certainly happened here. Frame limited to 23 or even 25 mils are a rarity on new bikes.

Comment: Alas, even expensive time trial bikes now come with 25 mm tyres https://bianchistore.online/bianchi-aquila-cv-138219/